# the Activity sometimes get started, sometimes not. why?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I'm using the below code to start an `Activity` from a `Service`:

```
public void startAct(){
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this, MyActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
}
```

it works on my device, also on emulator but I gave it to others to test. some of them say it simply doesn't work, other receive a force close. how is it possible? how to solve it?

Comment: is ur service called on any condition?

Comment: yes, there is a button in my main activity, on clicking that the service is started

Comment: just log some msg before starting intent u will come to know if ur service is called everytime or not

Comment: Users will find ways to break stuff. Do you have any log or crash reports?

Comment: I'm just sure that my service will start, I've logged it

Comment: so you all want to say that the above code is the correct form of starting an Activity from a Service?

Comment: This code looks fine. Probably your activity is crashing for those users. You'll need to check the code in `onCreate()` or whatever of your activity, that is probably where the problem is.